# Prune all git remotes

Tags: git

Does Git have anything akin to `git remote prune --all` to automatically prune all remotes in a repository? Is there anything more built-in (or elegant) than this bash loop I've used?

```
for REMOTE in `git remote`; do git remote prune $REMOTE; done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out Git *does* have this functionality, and it can be accomplished one of two ways:

1. `git remote update --prune` (ht. [morty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012586/morty))
2. `git fetch --prune --all`

Comment: Actually it has: `git remote update --prune` (as `git remote update` is the same as `git fetch --all`)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option. `git remote prune` doesn't even accept multiple remotes in the same command line.

You can use `xargs` with the `-n` option, instead of using a loop.

```
git remote | xargs -n1 git remote prune
```

See the [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) man page for more information